# Haskell Recursion Scanl

Tags: list, function, loops, haskell, recursion

I am trying to recursively pass in different values looping over eachother to be put into a function. I have this so far:

```
randNum f = take 20 (iterate f 300)
  where f n = scanl (mod') (n*2 + 75) getInts
```

(`getInts` is simply `cycle` and a list of numbers)

The `randNum` function is then used in the following way:

```
randGenPoints :: [Point]

randGenPoints = pairs (randNum 1)
```

However I have a problem where in the `randNum` I get this error:

```
*** Expression     : iterate f 300

*** Term           : f

*** Type           : Integer -> [Integer]

*** Does not match : [Integer] -> [Integer]
```

All I want is to have a continuously modifying list for the mod value in my function and i'm stuck and can't quite get it working....

Any advice would be much appreciated :),

Thanks

Comment: The expression `iterate f getInts` that's allegedly causing the problem does not turn up in the code you posted. Please add a full compilable example.

Comment: sorry, copied the wrong error. Was meant to be iterate f 300. Same error though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iterate` has type

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

It takes a function of type `a -> a`, which in your case is specialized to `Integer -> Integer`. However, the `f` you define in the where clause is of type `Integer -> [Integer]`. That happens because `scanl`, rather than just reducing a list to a value with some binary function, gives back a list with all intermediate values:

```
*Main> :t scanl
scanl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> [a]
*Main> scanl (+) 0 [1..5]
[0,1,3,6,10,15]
```

As far as the type errors go, you probably want a fold, such as `foldl'` from `Data.List`.

```
*Main> :t foldl'
foldl' :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
*Main> foldl' (+) 0 [1..5]
15
```

That, however, will not solve all of your problems. For one, if `getInts` is an infinite list as you imply, then a fold on it will not terminate.

P.S.: Note that, as Ingo pointed out, the `f` argument to `randNum` is not the same `f` defined in the where clause; it is superfluous.

Comment: - Cannot infer instance
*** Instance   : Real ((a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a)
*** Expression : f

Comment: `(a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a` is the type of `foldl'`, and the only thing in your code which asks for an instance of `Real` is `mod'` (assuming you got it from [`Data.Fixed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Fixed.html#v:mod%27)). The error makes it look like you tried `mod' foldl'` rather than `foldl' mod'`.

Comment: what if i want the numbers to be returned as doubles and  not integers? because i'm storing them in doubles. I tried fromIntegral but i'm getting problems.

Comment: The most natural way is applying `fromIntegral` to the list of generated numbers after the fact, as in `map fromIntegral generatedRands`. That way you don't have to bother with `mod'` (as plain `mod` will be enough), nor with doing floating point arithmetic in your algorithm.

Comment: This is pretty much what I have:randNum f = take 20 (iterate f 300)
  where f n = foldl' mod' (n*2 + 75) getInts

Comment: I tried randNum f = take 20 (iterate f 300)
  where f n = foldl' mod' (n*2 + 75) fromIntegral getInts, simply because there is a type mismatch where fromIntegral wants a -> b and getInts is [a]...

Comment: To apply an `a -> b` function to elements of an `[a]` list you need `map`. Your `where` definition would then be `f n = foldl' mod' (n*2 + 75) (map fromIntegral getInts)`. In any case, it is probably better to perform the `fromIntegral` conversion outside of your function, or at least outside of the core of the algorithm.

Comment: ah of course, because you would need to map the function fromIntegral on a specific x... haskell is a bit fresh with me. I only really know c++ and c# but i think i'm getting there. Thanks alot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `f`, and at the same time you're redefining `f`. While this is perhaps not the real error, it is quite confusing. Think about it and correct, please.

Answer (score -1):

For random numbers, you're using something like

```
nextPseudoRandom n =  n^2 +75 `mod` 234
```

right? You could maybe achieve what you want by doing

```
randNum = iterate (map nextPseudoRandom) (getInts)
```

so pointwise generated noise.

Comment: While that might kind-of work, it doesn't adress what the question really was about. Neither method would yield really "good" random numbers; if that was the question the answer would be to use a PRNG from the standard libraries. But it's not.

Comment: if you run randNum you don't get random numbers, you just get getInts... from my side anyway..

Comment: I want the value after mod to change continuously.. thats my point